# $(2, 1)$ is a point on the graph of $y = f(x)$. Find the corresponding point on the graph $y = 0.3f(5(x-3))$

Tags: functions

I took the approach I saw in my class:
$$y = 0.3f(5(x-3)) = 0.3f(5x-15)$$
$$(x, y) \mapsto (5x-15, 0.3y)$$
$$(2, 1) \mapsto (5(2)-15, 0.3(1)) = (-5, 0.3)$$

The problem is that my textbook says that $(3.4, 0.3)$ is the solution. I haven't a clue as to where I went wrong, so maybe someone on here can help?

Comment: Your answer asserts that $0.3 = 0.3f(5(-5 - 3)) = 0.3f(-40)$. How do you know this is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that

$$f(2)=1$$

Hence, to find a point that satisfies $y=0.3f(5(x-3))$

I shall let $$5(x-3)=2$$

Exercise: Solve for $x$.

Then $y=0.3f(2)=0.3$